# AngularJS data binding to HTML Table not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I have this code, from a tutorial I've followed online; unfortunately it's not working, and I can't find why because I'm mentioning the script, the app, the controller etc.. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: which angular version are you using?

Comment: Not sure if it's just a cut and paste error, but I see an extra comma in your angular script.

Comment: v1.3.16 downloaded from the official website

Comment: Where exactly @eat-sleep-code ?

Comment: @Chirac after the first object inside the logs array

Comment: Right before the last ];

Comment: @eat-sleep-code thanks for the fix, didn't solve the problem though.

Comment: Not a problem.   Just wanted to make sure it wasn't something silly.   Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @Chirac check answers, it solves the problem :)

Comment: Can you test if the controller is successfully associated with the template, and if the data is being successfully set in `$scope.logs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your .js to this:

```
var app = angular.module("queryLogTool",   []);

app.controller("queryLogToolController", function ($scope) {
$scope.logs = [
                {
                    'Issuer': 'AngularJSTest',
                    'Issue': 'AngularJS not working',
                    'Priority': 'High',
                    'Status': 'Open',
                    'DateOfIssue': '19/01/2015',
                    'DateResolved': '19/04/2015'
                }

              ];

});
```

Look at this plnkr: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KtqgJCKYnXbB4PAEtfF2?p=preview)

Comment: Are you sure this is fixing the problem? Testing it in JSFiddle doesn't work.

Comment: Indeed it's working in PInkr, but not in JSFiddle or in my Visual Studio. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong in this.

Comment: @Chirac have you check your libraries? I'm using 1.3.16 as you said. Open your application, press F12 in **Chrome** and check your console log.

Comment: Thanks for the console log advice! Helped me discover that the angular was not defined because you need to include angular first and put the script right below the code! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am new to angular, but I think you are calling your module right after you create it and you don't need to do that. Remove .queryLogTool that is right before .controller. It should look like:

angular.module("queryLogTool",   []).controller("queryLogToolController", function ($scope) {